# I want to know where in the program loads the image?. I'm using Visual c ++ 2012 and the first version of OpenCV

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012

//I'm using Visual c ++ and OpenCV version 1 and my question here is part of the code that //loads the image. Thanks for the replies.
     #include
     #include /* This is a standalone program. Pass an image name as a first  //parameter of the program. Switch between standard and probabilistic Hough transform by //changing "#if 1" to "#if 0" and back */

```
    #include<math.h> //Here are called OpenCV libraries

    intmain(intargc, char** argv) //In this part of the Nose code that does just wanted to give me a little help
    {
    IplImage* src;//In that part of the code is that it loads the image that is going to work?
    if( argc == 2 && (src=cvLoadImage(argv[1], 0))!= 0) //I want to know where in the program loads the image?, 
        {
    IplImage* dst = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src), 8, 1 );//here let me know meaning 'dst'?
    IplImage* color_dst = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src), 8, 3 );
    CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);//This line of code would know what it means or does?
    CvSeq* lines = 0;//I wonder that is this part of the code
    int i;
    cvCanny( src, dst, 50, 200, 3 );
    cvCvtColor( dst, color_dst, CV_GRAY2BGR );
    #if 1//This part is where it starts to detect the lines and then draw
    lines = cvHoughLines2( dst, storage, CV_HOUGH_STANDARD, 1, CV_PI/180, 100, 0, 0 );

    for( i = 0; i < MIN(lines->total,100); i++ )
            {
    float* line = (float*)cvGetSeqElem(lines,i);
    float rho = line[0];
    float theta = line[1];
    CvPoint pt1, pt2;
    double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
    double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho;
                pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b));
                pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a));
                pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b));
                pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a));
    cvLine( color_dst, pt1, pt2, CV_RGB(255,0,0), 3, 8 );//This is the part of the code where you start drawing lines, the lines to be drawn are red.
            }
    #else
    lines = cvHoughLines2( dst, storage, CV_HOUGH_PROBABILISTIC, 1, CV_PI/180, 50, 50, 10 );
    for( i = 0; i <lines->total; i++ )
            {
    CvPoint* line = (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(lines,i);
    cvLine( color_dst, line[0], line[1], CV_RGB(255,0,0), 3, 8 );
            }
    #endif
    cvNamedWindow( "Source", 1 );//My question is where is that the image is loaded ?? I do not see anywhere any extension jpg, bmp, etc
    cvShowImage( "Source", src );

    cvNamedWindow( "Hough", 1 );
    cvShowImage( "Hough", color_dst );

    cvWaitKey(0);//so that the image is maintained for a long period. Well I think so: D
        }
    }
```

Comment: intmain(intargc, char** argv) //In this part of the Nose code that does just wanted to give me a little help
    {
    IplImage* src;//In that part of the code is that it loads the image that is going to work?
    if( argc == 2 && (src=cvLoadImage(argv[1], 0))!= 0) //I want to know where in the program loads the image?, 
        {

Comment: if( argc == 2 && (src=cvLoadImage(argv[1], 0))!= 0) //In this part of the code is loading an image? That is my question.

Comment: please stop it. do not try to fix that code. throw it away, and use something more modern instead. PLEASE!

Comment: In any case I could spend some code to detect lines using HoughLines2 () To use in OpenCV 1.?

Comment: yes, totally outdated. please, again, prefer the [opencv tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html) to anything you might find on SO.

Comment: a) Please state your question explicitly. Don't post a long code block and hide your question in the comments. b) Where you say *"code is loading an image?"*, did you try looking at the documentation to find out what that function does? Seems easy enough to verify by yourself.

Comment: if( argc == 2 && (src=cvLoadImage(argv[1], 0))!= 0) //In this part of the code is loading an image? That is my question.

Comment: What I do is once applied in cvCanny apply HoughLines2 () so that the lines are drawn in the image. That's all I wanna do I have the Visual C ++ 2012 and OpenCV version 1.

Comment: I know; out of courtesy for others please do include this information at the top of your question. You want to make it as easy as possible to answer your question. Now, did you attempt to look up what cvLoadImage does? Was anything in the documentation about cvLoadImage unclear?

Comment: @JesusGonzales, it is *forbidden* to use opencv1.0 in 2014. don't be a moron, and insist on that.

Comment: That should do anyway? my teacher is telling me to use that version :(

Comment: Mat src = imread(filename, 0);  //What makes this part of the code? .Thanks friends

Comment: Mat dst, cdst; //What makes this part of the code? .Thanks friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please, it's almost 2015 now.

- do *not* even vaguely try to use opencv1.x, current stable version is 2.4.9
- the opencv world has changed *a lot* since 2010, they moved to a c++ api, and so should you.
- if you see any code containing IplImges, *leave it in it's well deserved grave*.
- if you really want to use Houghlines, look [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html#hough-lines)

to answer your question, here's how to load an image:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp" // proper c++ headers.
using namespace cv;


int main()
{
    Mat img = imread("lena.png"); // that's it already.
    if ( img.empty() )            // check, if it loaded.
    {
         return -1;
    }
    imshow("lena", img);
    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```